# Should we allow, even encourage, "feature comparison style" questions?

Tags: discussion

The more specific the piece of technology one uses, the more difficult it is for someone without extensive knowledge of that piece of technology to make informed decisions as to how best to use it.

In our case, DBMSes these days support very advanced features such that most developers, even DBAs, don't understand the difference between them, or when to use which features to achieve their requirements.

One example is the concept of high availability and how to achieve this. Many questions are asked about creating replicated databases using a variety of techniques (streaming replication, log shipping, file system or block level replication options) and brandishing about a variety of terms (eg cold/warm/hot standby) and confusing many other related technologies (clustering, sharding).

More generally, "askers" here -- more than on eg the original SO site -- confuse features with requirements and are asking questions about feature X when really they are trying to fulfill requirement Y and would be much better off using feature Z.

Should we allow -- even encourage -- questions such as [PostgreSQL Failover strategy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66375/postgresql-failover-strategy?noredirect=1#comment120346_66375) to help us all to navigate these mazes? At least on SO, questions such as this are very quickly closed as "too broad", "tip of the iceberg" or "unclear".